# Equivalent in C++ of an array with unidentified length

Tags: c#, c++, arrays

Let us consider this line of code in C# :

`int[] int_array;`

What is its equivalent in C++?

Is it : `int* int_array` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent in c++ is

```
std::vector<int> int_array;
```

Comment: My C++ is a bit rusty but doesn't this instantiate an empty vector? The C# code is an unassigned variable that doesn't allocate anything.